# How to set the value of the data held by the variable rather than the variable itself?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have variable x.

x is equal to `document.querySelector('h1').textContent;`

Is it possible to set the value of text content rather than reassigning the value of the variable using `=` or some other JavaScript operation? I know that I could just set x to `document.querySelector('h1');` and reassign the text by doing `x.textContent = 'Hello.'` I'd just like to know if there is some operation to avoid that.

I've tried changing the variable type to let, const, and var.

When I do this

```
let x = document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
x = 'Hi.'
```

It only reassigns the x variable to hold the value 'Hi.'
I wanna know if there's a way to assign the textContent of h1 using the variable without having to change the value of the variable to hold just the h1 element.

I can't come up with a google search query that gives back the results I want. "How to change the value of the data held in the variable rather than the variable" is the best I've come up with and nothing matches what I'm searching. Thanks.

Comment: No. The `.textContent` value will be a simple string, so the string value is copied as such to the variable. Strings are immutable.

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to be able to reassign a value of a given variable? If so, "pointing a new value to the variable" is the answer. Consider this explanation from "Eloquent JavaScript" — `You should imagine bindings as tentacles, rather than boxes. They do not _contain_ values; they _grasp_ them—two bindings can refer to the same value. A program can access only the values that it still has a reference to. When you need to remember something, you grow a tentacle to hold on to it or you reattach one of your existing tentacles to it.`

Comment:  ([link here](https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html)). In other words, you're always pointing at a certain value for a given variable; you won't be directly _changing_ the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript. They can't be altered. You need to reassign the property or call a setter on the object holding the string when you want to change the string being held.

With *mutable* objects, this is easy:

```
const x = [];
x.push(1);
```

But this only works because arrays have methods on them that allow them to be mutated (via `push` here). Strings don't expose any such methods because they don't support mutation.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do like this

```
let x = document.querySelector('h1');

function updateTextContent(newText)
{
  x.textContent = newText
}

//now you can call like this:
updateTextContent('Hi.');
```